# Traverse of multidimensional Array in any axis

Tags: c++, c++11, multidimensional-array

I have a (kind of) performance problem in my code, that roots in the chosen architecture.

I will use multidimensional tensors (basically matrices with more dimensions) in the form of cubes to store my data. 
Since the dimension is not known at compile-time, I can't use Boost's MultidimensionalArray (IIRC), but have to come up, with my own solution.

Right now, I save each dimension, on it's own. I have a Tensor of dimension (let's say 3), that holds a lot of tensors of dimension 2 (in an std::vector), that each have a std::vector with tensors of dimension 1, that each holds a std::vector of (numerical) data. I use an abstract base-class for my tensor, so everything in there is a pointer to the abstract class, while beeing (secretly) multi- or one-dimensional.

I extract a single numerical data-point by giving a std::list of indices to a tensor, that get's the first element, searches for the according tensor and passes the rest of the list to that tensor in a (kind of) recursive call.

I now have to do a multi-dimensional Fast-Fourier Transformation on that data. I use a Threadpool and Job-Objects, that works on copying data from an Tensor along one dimension, doing an FFT and writes that data back.

I already have logic to implement ThreadPool and organize the dimensions to FFT along, but there is one problem:

My data-structure is the cache-unfriendliest beast, one can think of... While the Data-Copying along the first dimension (that, with it's data in a single 1D-Tensor) is reasonable fast, but in other directions, I need to copy my data from all over the place.

Since there are no race-conditions (I make sure every concurrent FFT is on distinct data-points), I thought, I would not use a Mutex-Guard to let everybody copy at the same time. However this heavily slows down the process ("I copy my data now!" - "No, I copy my data now!"- "But it's my turn now!"...)

Guarding the copy-Process with a mutex, does not increase speed. The FFT of a vector with 1024 elements is way faster, then the copy-process to get these elements, resulting in nearly all of my threads waiting, while one is copying.

Long story short: 
Is there any kind of multi-dimensional data-structure, that does not need to set the dimension at compile-time, that allows me to traverse fast along all axis? I searched for a while now, by nothing came up besides Boost MultiArray. Vectorization also does not work since the indices would grow too fast to hold in usual int-types.

---

I can't think of how to present code-examples here, since most of that code is rather simple, but If needed, I can get that in.

Comment: rather than allocate vector of vectors (of vectors), can't you use a vector of dimension sizes and then one vector to store all data?

Comment: The sizes in every dimension is the same. My data are all hypercubes (for now). The Problem with putting all data in a single vector is the indexing. I tried to index the vector, but I failed, for too small int-types.

Comment: Just an idea, could you subdivide the whole thing into smaller hypercubes? Assuming that the sub-processes are not that often in the same hypercube, this would mean that they could access data undisturbed until they jump to the next hypercube.

Comment: @Laray: What do you mean "too small int-types"?  Surely you're using a 64-bit platform, where `size_t` is 64 bits?  What exactly is too small?

Comment: As I tried that, I was not able to calculate the size of the single vector (setting to zero at a certain value). As I was using *long long int* as index it gave me an error of not being able to use it with std::vector for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

[Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/unsupported/group__CXX11__Tensor__Module.html) has multi-dimensional tensor support (nominally unsupported, but written by the DeepMind people, so "somewhat" supported?), and FFTW has 1d to 3d FFTs. Using external libraries with a set of 1D to 3D FFTs would outsource most of the hard work.

Edit: Actually, FFTW has support for threaded n-dimensional FFTs

Comment: Look's very good so far. Right now it's quite hard for me (being more a math guy than CS guy) to understand how that module works, but I will take a look at it!